# ¿como se suma los valores de una matriz 4x5 sin sumar los de la diagonal principal en java?

Tags: java

nos hicieron una pregunta en clase ¿como se suma los valores de una matriz 4x5 sin sumar los de la diagonal principal? estaría contento con la solución a ese problema.
Gracias..

Comment: Lo puedes hacer recorriendo toda la matriz. Necesitarás, una variable para acumular la suma, y dos variables para iterar por cada fila y cada columna. En cada iteración, si el valor de fila y columna son distintos, acumulas el valor del elemento que está en esa posición, si la fila y la columna son iguales, no acumulas el valor (si la fila y la columna son iguales es que ese elemento se encuentra en la diagonal principal)

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @ordago: no respondas en los comentarios. XD (es broma)

Comment: @MauricioContreras ;-) sabía que alguna colleja me iba a llevar jeje.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero crea otra variable `resultado` del mismo tipo que las matrices para guardar el resultado.
Tienes multiples opciones, te expongo dos:

Opción 1:
Recorrer la matrices `m1` y `m2` elemento por elemento con dos bucles `for`, por ejemplo con los indices `i`, `j`

```
    if(i=j) {resultado[i][j]=0;}
    else {resultado[i][j]=m1[i][j]+m2[i][j];}
```

Opción 2: Usar el procedimiento normal de suma de dos matrices (como te hayan enseñado) y posteriormente asignar el valor 0 a la diagonal, es menos eficiente, pero con un bucle `for` en este caso sería suficiente.

Otras opciones. Si dispones de una clase para la operaciones de matrices, crear una matriz de unos de la misma dimensiones con la diagonal ceros y multiplicar el resultado.

Hay multitud de soluciones. De cualquier forma, creo que una de las mas eficientes es la primera.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero debemos evitar responder preguntas mal formuladas. Sobre todo preguntas que piden que le hagan los deberes al OP. Estas preguntas terminan cerradas y tu respuesta se pierde (ya no será visible). Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos